# Which control is suitable for my application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vba

Now i am currently working on a c# based application.In that application now i am working on design part.i am using visual studio 2008,i want a control like below image[image: tools]

which control is available like above image in visual studio.
i tried treeview.but i can't get the link like above image(here link is blue line).
How to do this?

Comment: *"but i can't get the link like above image(here link is blue line)."* That doesn't make any sense. This is a `TreeView` control, but you'll need to owner draw it if you want all those arrows everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you move to some new technologies, most of the new features will available to you.

if you use WPF, you can achieve it. there is much flexibility in UI Decoration in it.

your desired design with custom item icons and colour [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/01/14/part-i-_3a00_traffic-alert-app-_2d00_-take-the-pain-out-of-driving.aspx)

if you use red controls: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreelistview-visual-structure.html)

Comment: WPF is not required to achieve either of the effects that you link to...